# Is it possible to progressively taper a CSS 'border-right' like a needle?

Tags: html, css

Edit: *old question was using images which have since expired; rewritten the same question.

I am needing to progressively taper a line in css to sub-single pixel widths. This is to mimic a design which was handed to me, imagine a single-side border with 2px width progressively thinning along a line until it's nothing.

Any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: since you did it cubic, why should border-radius not work ?

Comment: I need a progressive tapering - not one over ~5 pixels.

Comment: You can use a combination of `border-image` and css `linear-gradient`

Comment: check [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) out.

Comment: Or you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to achieve this effect.

Comment: Without any of your HTML/CSS , to have an answer that works means here to do the job for you ... unless you provide what you did here and within a fiddle to ease people willing to help you

Comment: Thanks guys. @GC I don't understand why you're asking for a fiddle. I'm asking for the elements / styling examples so I can do the work myself. This is because I want to know what properties I have forgotten to think of and I can use them in the future. I don't want someone just giving me perfectly fitting code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, a quick example ([**live demo**](http://jsbin.com/qofitayi/1/)):

HTML:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main-nav {
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#main-nav a {
  display: block;
}

#main-nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -10%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 120%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #666 75%, transparent);
}

#main-nav:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #666 75%, transparent);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/EY5LC/1/)**.  This is only any use if you a) are happy with CSS only and b) don't want any content in the `div`.

Think of the `border-top` and `border-left` as sort `x` and `y` coordinates.

By specifying a `width` and `height` of `0px`, it allows you to shape the `div` purely using your borders:

```
div {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:solid 5px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top:solid 50px  rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-right:solid 5px blue;
    border-bottom:solid 50px blue;
}
```

Bear in mind that this approach only allows linear tapering.